# C# to Teamcity NTLM Authentication failing

Tags: c#, teamcity

I'm unable to authenticate with Teamcity from C# with NTLM. It works in the browser and with Postman.

With logging turned on it seems to do the NTLM handshake, but then settles on a 401 error with:

```
The token supplied to the function is invalid
To login manually go to "/login.html" page
```

Sample code is below. I'm not sure what's wrong here. It works with Basic authentication and a modified URI including httpAuth.

```
        string uri = "http://teamcityserver/ntlmAuth/action.html?add2Queue=SomeBuild";

        CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(new Uri(uri), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("user", "password")); // Have also tried default credentials

        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Credentials = cc;
        req.Headers.Add("Origin: http://teamcity");
```

Comment: AFAIK when dealing with Windows accounts, you must include the domain name (or lacking a domain, the local computer name) as part of the user name, e.g. `domain\user`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 There's a 3 argument version of NetworkCredential with the domain as the 3rd argument which I've also tried without success. I did add it into the user field just in case, but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The missing factor was that the cookies were not being sent by the client during the NTLM back-and-forth.

Adding this fixed it:

```
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```